# Find command to search specific folder name than search within the result

Tags: unix

I have bunch of wordpress sites that are hosted in shared hosting environment. As with every wordpress site there are "uploads" directory. I would like to search for potentially malicious files that are within those folders regularly but i dont want to ofcourse do it one by one.

So question is how can i search all "uploads" directories for a file with extension ".php"

For example:

`find . -type d -iname "uploads"`

gets me all the "uploads" folders in my root directory but i also want to search within those director

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to pipe the output from your command to another, but you can search for both criteria at once, using [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) and [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info):

```
find . -type f | grep -i "/uploads/.*\.php$"
```

How it works:

- `find . -type f` lists **all** files in the current directory and its subdirectories.
- `grep -i "/uploads/.*\.php$"` filters the output:

  - `-i` makes the search case-insensitive
  - `/uploads/.*\.php$` is the regular expression a line has to match in order to get displayed

    - `/uploads/` `php` are exactly that
    - `.*` is any number of occurrences of any type of characters
    - `\.` is a literal `.`
    - `$` signals the end of the line

You can achieve the same result with

```
find . -type f -iregex ".*/uploads/.*\.php"
```

but the syntax is a hassle if you know Regular Expressions from `grep`, Perl, PHP, JavaScript, etc.